# Port scanner in python3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am learning to program in python3, I've been learning for a month, so I decided to try the python's socket module and make a port scanner.

```
import socket
host = input("Host: ")
port = int(input("Port: "))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect((host, port))
except:
    print(str(port) + " isnt open")
else: 
    print(str(port) + " is open")
```

The issue with the code is that the ports are never open, even the most common ones like 80 or 443.
So I'm asking for you guys to help me fixing eventual bugs.

Comment: Hi there, I have been trying out your code, and manage to find open ports.
for host: google.com port: 443 I manage to get a port is open. So I feel your code is correct. You may want to had ask something more specific, or show us some of the tests your ran that made you conclude your code was incorrect

Answer (score 1):

I think another error is happening.
Have you tried printing the exception inside the `except` block?

```
import socket
host = input("Host: ")
port = int(input("Port: "))
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect((host, port))
except Exception as err:
    print(str(port) + " isnt open")
    print(err.args) #for debugging
else: 
    print(str(port) + " is open")
```

This would let you see the actual error.

Comment: Indeed this is a good idea to gain a deeper insight. By doing so I manage to get 
Host: 0.0.0.0
Port: 443
443 isnt open
(111, 'Connection refused')
it seems not that the port is not open but I was actively kick out when trying to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
import socket

host = str(input("Host: "))
port = int(input("Port: "))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = s.connect_ex((host,port))

if result == 0:
    print('Port', port, 'is open')
else: 
    print('Port', port, 'is closed')
```